# Formulário de Login

Tags: php, html, login

Meu código HTML do formulário da tela de login (**login.html**):

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="login.php">
          <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>

          <input type="email" name="user" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

          <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"><div class="remb">Lembrar-me</div>
              </label>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" value="submit">Sign in</button>
</form><!-- /form -->
```

Quando clico no botão de submit, tendo digitado um e-mail e uma senha qualquer, o navegador me oferece para abrir um arquivo php, quando eu o abro, ele está com o código presente no arquivo **login.php**. Não importando o que haja nesse arquivo.

Comment: Como assim? O codigo que voce colocou é exatamente como está o seu código? digo, esta o código completo ai?

Comment: Não, meu arquivo html possui mais coisa. Acha necessário eu postar o resto?

Comment: Coloca ele completo, porque pode haver algo interferindo. Pois aparentemente o seu código esta normal

Comment: O código php está escrito na tela como se fosse um texto comum, é isso?

Comment: Vc está abrindo seu arquivo por algum programa(XAMPP ou WAMP)?

Comment: Sim, André. E não, gilmar.

Answer (score 2):

Fica desse jeito? Se sim, vc está abrindo ele do jeito errado, para abrir é necessário ter instalado o apache no seu sistema, ou abrir ele com algum programa que simula um servidor web(WAMP, XAMPP, EASY PHP e etc.).

*OBS: Ignore o código, eu peguei na internet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, fica desse jeito, por exemplo. Como faço para instalar apache no meu sistema? Recomenda algum tutorial?

Comment: Link -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH86D2gGcK8

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Simulador de servidores web -> http://www.wampserver.com

Comment: https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html

Comment: http://www.easyphp.org

Answer (score 0):

Os seus arquivos precisam estar em algum servidor (pode ser local) que tenha suporte ao php.
O que está ocorrendo, é aue você está abrindo o arquivo .html pelo navegador (botao direito -> abrir com o navegador). No caso do html funciona normal, pois o próprio navegador tem suporte ao html assim.
Já com o php, é diferente. Por isso ele abre o arquivo como se fosse um "arquivo de texto".

Você pode usar programas como o XAMPP, Vertrigo, IIS para seu problema.

Outra coisa que pode acontecer, é você estar utilizando um serviço de hospedagem que não suporte php. Neste caso, converse com a hospedagem ou procure uma nova.